# Term for the diameter of the complement of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Have you heard of one?

Comment: Please explain more clearly.  How do you describe the complement of a graph without embedding it somewhere?

Comment: Complement $\bar{G}$ being the graph on the same set of vertices with $\{u,v\} \in V(\bar{G})$ if and only if $\{u,v\} \notin V(G)$.  That's how I would describe it.

Comment: Those V's should be E's of course.  I have a headache.

Comment: How about "complementary diameter"?

Comment: I'd call it the "complementary diameter", like Greg, and perhaps shorten it to "codiameter".

Comment: Does it need a term?  How's about "diameter of $\bar{G}$" or $\text{diam}(\bar{G})$ (or similar)?

Comment: I'm more interested in terms that are already in use (for lit. searching purposes).  If I were introducing one, I'd definitely go with "complementary diameter".  Codiameter, interestingly enough, already means something else.  

I think the lack of an answer thus far is a pretty conclusive answer.  :)